# Jasper Report Creation - Suppress and Hide Pagination Headers

Tags: java, excel, pdf, pagination, jasper-reports

I am developing a Java application to generate reports from ".jasper" report files created in iReports. When the reports are generated in PDF, I would like to retain column labels and pagination info on each individual page. However, when exported as an excel spreadsheet or pure HTML, I only want the column headers once. Can anyone suggest settings that I can pass programmatically in Java to the Jasper API to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple settings you need to setup in the exporter to export it as one page:

```
reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE); 
reportExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Now this only gets you part of the way. Since it will still print the page header and page footer once each. You need to add a boolean parameter to the report that indicates whether or not to print those bands. You would set this in the `printWhenExpression` for the bands.

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally add `JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION` as below to suppress the generation of column headers when exporting to excel. Works with Jasper Reports 5.5.

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
        parameters.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledReport, parameters, 
                (jrDataSource == null) ? new JREmptyDataSource() : jrDataSource);
```